# I want to add an span after nav container in WP menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

Here is the code,

```
$args = array( 
        'container'         => 'nav',
        'container_id'      => 'menu', 
        'menu_class'        => 'menu clearfix', 
        'fallback_cb'       => 'mfn_wp_page_menu', 
        'depth'             => 5,
        'link_before'       => '<span>',
        'link_after'        => '</span>',
    );
```

here is the output html ,

```
<nav id="menu34" class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu clearfix">
  <li><a href=""><span>HOME</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I need to an span after the `<nav>` .

Please help out.

Comment: A `<span>` by itself doesn't do anything. What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: Is this the code of the span you want to add? please clarify your question and specifically show the span code that you want to add after wp navigation menu. what is $args = array() for?

Comment: please share your web link

Comment: @Difster I want to write an css for span .

Comment: do you want span after `<nav id="menu34" class="menu-main-menu-container"><span></span></nav>`? or `<li><a href=""><span>`

Comment: @NaeemUlWahhab i need to add an css for it. An <span> or <div class="" > , i just want to add it after the <nav> .

Comment: @vel it should be like <nav id="menu34" class="menu-main-menu-container"><span><ul></ul></span></nav>

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following code which helps me to do same :

```
<nav class="container_class">
<span>
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'  => 'primary','menu_id'=> 'main-menu','container'=>false,'fallback_cb'=>'mfn_wp_page_menu','menu_class'=>'menu clearfix','depth'=>5,));    
?>
</span>
</nav>
```

The above code will not ad any container with the menu listing. So you can add as per your choice.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i think my question is not clear . I need that container class too .That is <nav> </nav> . i need to add an span/div after the <nav> .Like , <nav><span></span></nav>

Comment: So you can add the class to "nav" tag. like : <nav class="container_class">

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$args = array( 
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_id'      => 'menu', 
    'menu_class'        => 'menu clearfix', 
    'fallback_cb'       => 'mfn_wp_page_menu', 
    'depth'             => 5,
    'link_before'       => '<span>',
    'link_after'        => '</span>',
);



<nav id="menu34" class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <div>//your div
        <?php       
            $args = array(                  
                'container'      => FALSE,                  
            );
            wp_nav_menu($args);
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

or

```
$args = array( 
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_id'      => 'menu', 
    'container_class'   => 'you div class',
    'menu_class'        => 'menu clearfix', 
    'fallback_cb'       => 'mfn_wp_page_menu', 
    'depth'             => 5,
    'link_before'       => '<span>',
    'link_after'        => '</span>',
);


<nav id="menu34" class="menu-main-menu-container">

        <?php       
            $args = array(                  
                'container'      => true,                  
            );
            wp_nav_menu($args);
        ?>

</nav>
```